# XmlRpcStreamServer throws org.xml.sax.SAXParseException question

Tags: java, xml-rpc, saxparser

I am facing an org.xml.sax.SAXParseException and hope someone can explain this to me.

The stack trace is

```
Failed to parse XML-RPC request: Character reference "&#
org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Failed to parse XML-RPC request: Character reference "&#
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.getRequest(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:71)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.execute(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:199)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.XmlRpcServletServer.execute(XmlRpcServletServer.java:112)
    at org.app.servlets.MyXmlRpcServerServlet.doPost(MyXmlRpcServerServlet.java:96)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 382; Character reference "&#
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1234)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:525)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.getRequest(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:65)
    ... 17 more
Caused by:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 382; Character reference "&#
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1234)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:525)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.getRequest(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:65)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.execute(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:199)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.XmlRpcServletServer.execute(XmlRpcServletServer.java:112)
    at org.app.servlets.MyXmlRpcServerServlet.doPost(MyXmlRpcServerServlet.java:96)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

By googling this exception, I can find something like 
"org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "some characters" is an invalid XML", which makes sense.
But what is

```
Failed to parse XML-RPC request: Character reference "&#
```

It seems missing "is an invalid XML" on the exception message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the error message says: the cause is an error in the xml document. Something near column 382 is malformed and the document can't be parsed.

I'd take the message, use some tool to apply proper indention (e.g. xml editor from eclipse wst plugin) and verify, if the document really is well-formed.

Comment: The exception is caught on the server log. I am not able to access the original document.

Comment: That makes it more complicated. Can you catch it on the client? Or - another practical approach, monitor/capture network traffic with wireshark and get the document from there? *Something* is sending invalid stuff.

Comment: Yes, this is the hard part. I have been trying to re-produce the exception in the last hours and still out of luck.